# How to create AjaxFormSubmitBehavior

Tags: java, wicket

in my form I just have one field without buttons:

```
add(new AutoCompleteTextField<String>("hladaneSlovo", settings) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected Iterator<String> getChoices(String input) {
                return new HladaneSlova().iterator();
            }
        }.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(this, "onsubmit") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                setResponsePage(new VyjimkyPage(parametry));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            }
        }));
```

problem is when I submit this form (just write word and then push enter) nothing happens. What is wrong ?

Comment: Do you have the submit() of your Form overriden? It schould get called.

Comment: onFormSubmitted is final method I cant override it

Comment: use onSubmit() not onFormSubmitted(). All you need is a <input type="submit"> in your form. no need to add a SubmitLink in java. Just in html and override the onSubmit() of the form

Comment: oh ok thx it work but I cant accept your answer because you add this jut in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous comment as an answer: No need for an AjaxFormSubmitBehavior. You need to override the the onSubmit() in your form:

```
Form form = new Form("form") {

   @Override
   public void onSubmit() {
      // do your stuff
   }

   @Override
   public void onError() {
      // you get here in case of errors (conversion/validatio)
   }
}
add(form);

form.add(...)
```

I 'm not 100% sure you need an button on your form. If you need one in html:

```
<form wicket:id="form">
   <input type="text" wicket:id="yourAutoComplete">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You will not need to conect the submit input element to a java component. But you can try without the submit element in html and see if it works.

Comment: You don't need the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the AjaxFormSubmitBehavior to the form instead adding it to the text field.

Comment: I try to add this behaviour to the form but still is doesnt work

Comment: Have you a Submit button attached to your form? Because when you hit the return key your browser tries to find the first submit button attached to the form and calls the submit action of this button.

Comment: I suggest you add a submit button or you add an AjaxEventBehavior to your textfield that listens to update events on this field.